# Chromebrowser show "data:," instead of the parameter passed in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run a simple URL to get started in chrome browser but getting just "data:,"My JDK ,selenium and browser are all latest version.

Chrome browser used - Version 76.0.3809.100(32 - Bit)
Java - JDK 1.8
Chromedriver used - ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126

Code used

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//import org.openga.selenium.Webdriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;   


public class CLMTWorkflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","H:\\Selenium Prerequisite\\Executables\\IEDriverServer.exe");

        //InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "H:\\Selenium Prerequisite\\Executables\\geckodriver.exe");  

        //FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "H:\\Selenium Prerequisite\\Executables\\chromedriver.exe");


        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();




        driver.get("https://www.myntra.com/");


    }

}
```

Comment: GIve it a try with latest chromedriver

Comment: Yes I also used the Latest stable release: ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40 but still getting same error.